# Take two elements and wrap them in a div and insert another div inside

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to wrap radio input with its label and then insert an element into the newly created wrapper, but between the input and the label, and I can't seem to find an easy way

I'd like to turn this

```
            <fieldset data-radio-req>
                <label>Choose Your Favorite</label>
                <input type="radio" name="pokemon" value="Red">
                <label>Red</label>
                <input type="radio" name="pokemon" value="Blue">
                <label>Blue</label>
                <span class="form-error">This field is required.</span>
            </fieldset>
```

Into this

```
            <fieldset data-radio-req>
                <label>Choose Your Favorite</label>
                <div class="toggle-box"> <!-- wrapper -->
                    <input type="radio" name="pokemon" value="Red">
                    <span><i></i></span> <!-- newly iserted -->
                    <label>Red</label>
                </div>
                <div class="toggle-box"> <!-- wrapper -->
                    <input type="radio" name="pokemon" value="Blue">
                    <span><i></i></span> <!-- newly iserted -->
                    <label>Blue</label>
                </div>
                <span class="form-error">This field is required.</span>
            </fieldset>
```

Currently I do

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(index) {
    $(this).next('label').andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='toggle-box'></div>");
});
```

But I don't know how to easily insert the `'<span><i></i></span>'` into the newly created `.toggle-box` between the `input` and the `label` without doing another `.each()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How about:**

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(index) {
    $(this).next('label').andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='toggle-box'></div>").parent().append('<span><i></i></span>');
});
```

**Please check below snippet.**

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(index) {
  $(this).next('label').andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='toggle-box'></div>").parent().append('<span><i></i></span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset data-radio-req>
  <label>Choose Your Favorite</label>
  <input type="radio" name="pokemon" value="Red">
  <label>Red</label>
  <input type="radio" name="pokemon" value="Blue">
  <label>Blue</label>
  <span class="form-error">This field is required.</span>
</fieldset>
```

or if you want the span between the input and the label:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(index) {
  $(this).next('label').andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='toggle-box'></div>").parent().find('label').before('<span><i></i></span>');
});
```

```js
  $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(index) {
  $(this).next('label').andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='toggle-box'></div>").parent().find('label').before('<span><i></i></span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset data-radio-req>
  <label>Choose Your Favorite</label>
  <input type="radio" name="pokemon" value="Red">
  <label>Red</label>
  <input type="radio" name="pokemon" value="Blue">
  <label>Blue</label>
  <span class="form-error">This field is required.</span>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Cheers man I knew it was gonna be simple.. I was doing .after and .append but didn't realize I need to the .parent first.. Thank you

Comment: One more question. How do I get the span between the `input` and the `label` ?

Comment: there is a css property called margin :)

Comment: How is margin gonna help me achieve that?

Comment: I meant instead of having `<div class="toggle-box"><input type="radio" name="pokemon" value="Blue"><label>Blue</label><span><i></i></span</div>` I need `<div class="toggle-box"><input type="radio" name="pokemon" value="Blue"><span><i></i></span><label>Blue</label></div>` so I can use `+` selector on the `span`.

Comment: you want the span between the input and the label?

Comment: I'd prefer it but its not necessary I guess, because I use `[type="radio"]:checked + span` to style a custom radio button, but then I also need to style the `label` which I will have to use `[type="radio"]:checked ~ label` for anyway so its fine. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So I do actually need the span in the middle. Sorry :( I'll edit the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123239/discussion-between-cream-whipped-airplane-and-madalin-ivascu).